# What is the proper way to trigger different functions on command click of status bar item in vs code extension api

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am using the VScode extensions api. I have an item like so.

```
const item = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(
    vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right
  );
```

it's command is set to the following

```
item.command = "codevids.record";
```

Which calls the `record()` function onClick

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand("codevids.record", () => record());
```

All of this makes sense to me for the most part. Now I am handling logic in the record function so that when it is clicked again it has a different effect, it determines this by what is in the status bar string.

Like so

```
const record = () => {
    if (item.text === `$(record) codevid` || item.text === `$(stop) codevid`) {
      item.text = `$(pass) codevid`;

      clearInterval(intervalID);
    } else {
      item.text = `$(record) codevid`;
```

There must be a more proper way to handle the status bar getting clicked in a boolean manner. I actually want a click to play, click to pause, and click done and run different functions.

What are my options in this regard.

Thanks ahead of time, and please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a switch statement, maybe there is a more vscode way of doing it instead of checking against the string in the status bar, but works for now.

````
const record = async () => {
    console.log(item.text);

    switch (item.text) {
      case `$(device-camera-video) codevid`:
        console.log("recording");
        item.text = `$(record) codevid`;
        break;
      case `$(record) codevid`:
        console.log("recording options");
        const go = vscode.window
          .showErrorMessage("Pause or Finish", "Pause", "Finish")
          .then((selection) => {
            if (selection === "Pause") {
              item.text = `$(debug-pause) codevid`;
            } else if (selection === "Finish") {
              item.text = `$(pass) codevid`;
            }
            return selection;
          });
        console.log("go", await go);
        break;
      case `$(debug-pause) codevid`:
        console.log("paused");
      case `$(pass) codevid`:
        console.log("finished");
      default:
        console.log("default");
    }
    ```
````